# Domain created a separate mesh

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

Attempted to apply a quick smoke and fire effect to the default cube in blender but instead of setting the cube on fire the domain created a separate mesh and ran the simulation on that. After searching around online I have no idea why this happened or how to fix it.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, Devin.  From what I see, it did add the Domain "cube" as you call it.  That is not a mesh, it is a 3d Domain boundary within which the simulation will take effect, and ignore anything outside the boundary.   If you visit your Cube and look at the Physics Properties, you'll see that the Quick Smoke added a Fluid -> Flow -> Smoke property so that it will be the initial Geometry, which you can change to Inflow if you want it to continuously emit smoke.   Fluid Physics manual covers all of this https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/physics/fluid/index.html

Comment: Also, be sure to search for "blender smoke tutorial" in your favorite search engine.